# Scale vertical (z) axis of 3D surface plot with plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

How can I scale the Z-axis of a surface plot in matplotlib? Take the following example dataset and plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# Generate a 3D surface 
z = np.exp(-0.1*x**2 - 0.1*y**2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Create the surface plot
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='plasma')
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d plot]

And I want to scale it so it looks like the below plot (which I have done by adjusting the axis limits) but with with the z-axis limits still between 0 and 1. Is this possible? I couldn't find anything in the docs about how to do this. For illustration the [`persp`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/persp) function in R has the `expand` argument that does exactly what I want to do.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Create the surface plot
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='plasma')
ax.set_zlim([0, 2.5])
plt.show()
```

[image: Scaled 3d plot]

---

### Update

For clarification, here's an example of exactly what I'm trying to do using R code. I'm trying to adjust the z-axis aspect ratio. With the `persp` function in R we can just use the `expand argument to do this. For example:

```
# Generate synthetic data for demonstration purposes
x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
z <- matrix(0, length(x), length(y))

# Generate a Gaussian surface
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  for(j in 1:length(y)) {
    z[i, j] <- exp(-0.1 * x[i]^2 - 0.1 * y[j]^2)
  }
}

nrz <- nrow(z)
ncz <- ncol(z)
# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#0d0887", "#cc4678", "#f0f921"))
# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
```

#### expand = 1.0

```
persp(x, y, z, theta = 45, phi = 30, expand = 1.0, col = color[facetcol])
```

[image: expand = 1.0]

#### expand = 0.3

```
persp(x, y, z, theta = 45, phi = 30, expand = 0.3, col = color[facetcol])
```

[image: expand = 0.3]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Are you looking to remap/normalize your Z values?

Comment: @jared, I want to scale the Z axis to make the plot look less "steep" (like in the second figure) but without having the extend the z-axis. In other words I want to adjust the image aspect ratio of the z-axis.

Comment: @Jared I have added an update for clarification.

Comment: Why is adjusting the limits not good enough?

Comment: Because I don't want to have the extra z-axis values > 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to change the aspect ratio of the 3D plot. Following your R example where you change the aspect ratio to be 0.3 in the z, you can do this in matplotlib using the [`ax.set_box_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect.html) function. The function takes a tuple that provides the XYZ ratios.

```py
ax.set_box_aspect((1,1,0.3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate z scaled and put into your plot. Here is the sample:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Generate a 3D surface
z = np.exp(-0.1*x**2 - 0.1*y**2)

# Find the maximum value in the original "z" values
max_z = z.max()

# Calculate the scaling factor to make the max_z equal to 1
scaling_factor = 1 / max_z
 
# Scale the "z" values
z_scaled = z * scaling_factor

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Create the surface plot with the scaled z-values
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z_scaled, cmap='plasma')

# Set Z-axis limits between 0 and 1
ax.set_zlim([0, 1])

plt.show()
```

And here is the sample result:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply Heinz. To clarify I'm not looking to scale the values of Z but scale the actual axis. in other words I want to adjust the aspect ratio of the axes (in particular the vertical axis). I want the plot to resemble the second figure but without the extra unnecessary Z-axis values.